# How to get to the expected result in wxMaxima

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima

The problem seems to be simple, but I don't know how to get the solution

### Entered in wxMaxima

```
xt:xm-w/2;
z:w/(xmax-xmin+2*ma);
xa:xt/z;
x:xa+xmax/2+xmin/2;

expand(x);
              -(xm*xmin)/w + xmin + (xm*xmax)/w + (2*ma*xm)/w - ma
```

This is OK, but we can simplify a bit deeper.

### Simplified by myself

```
x =  -(xm*xmin)/w + xmin + (xm*xmax)/w + (2*ma*xm)/w - ma
x = xm/w * (xmax-xmin + 2*ma) + xmin - ma
or
z = w/(xmax-xmin+2*ma)

So
x = xm/z + xmin - ma
```

Question:

Is there a possibility in wxMaxima to get this result ?

```
x = xm/z + xmin - ma
```

Thanks in advance

Christian

Answer (score 1):

You can try using equations instead of variables:

```
(%i) remvalue(all)$
(%i) EQ1:xt=xm-w/2$
(%i) EQ2:z=w/(xmax-xmin+2*ma)$
(%i) EQ3:xa=xt/z,[EQ1,EQ2]$
(%i) EQ4:x=xa+xmax/2+xmin/2,[EQ3]$
(%i) EQ5:solve([EQ2],w)$
(%i) EQ4,[EQ5]$
(%i) expand(%);
(%o) x=xm/z+xmin-ma
```

for better understanding:

```
xa=xt/z,[EQ1,EQ2];
```

is the short form of:

```
ev(xa=xt/z,[xt=xm-w/2,z=w/(xmax-xmin+2*ma)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Meantime I found the other solution. Thanks :-)

```
xt:xm-w/2;
z:w/(xmax-xmin+2*ma);
xa:xt/z;
x:xa+xmax/2+xmin/2;
w:solve('z=z,w)[1];
x:subst(w,x);
expand(x);
```